# Prevenir error de consulta

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo esta consulta en Linq:

```
var results = (from u in db.datos
                      where u.IdLogin == id
                      select u).ToList();
```

El problema surge cuando el usuario no ha llenado sus datos y me marca un error ya que no encuentra resultados, lo había solucionado con un `try` y `catch` pero me gustaría saber si existe otra forma de poder solucionar este error.

Comment: ¿El error te salta en la linea del results, o despues?

Comment: Si te refieres a `id`, comprueba que no este vacío antes de ejecutar la consulta

Comment: Que tal gracias por sus comentarios pero ese no es el problema, ya que mi id tiene valor el problema es que el usuario en la tabla datos aún no llena su registro y cuando busca con el id muestra el error ya que no encuentra resultados

Comment: no te sigo.. no devuelve un results vacio?

Comment: No, no lo devuelve, devuelve un error con la bd lo cual es ilogico porqué cuando existe un registro si me devuelve los valores.

Comment: ¿y cuál es el error que te devuelve?

Comment: Puedes dar un poco mas detalle o mostrar parte del codigo?

Comment: Sería interesante tambien que pulses en [edit] y añadas la excepción que te lanza.